# .Net use of special folder notation

Tags: .net, windows, special-folders

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
IO.Directory.Exists("%USERPROFILE%")
```

The reason being that I want to specify one of the directories which my application will use, as plain text in a config file. In some cases I will want it to be nested under the user profile, in which case the config file would read something like:

```
...
LocalDbDirectory = %USERPROFILE%\Application Data\My Toolkit\
...
```

Or I might want it to be in a network location, in which case it would read something like:

```
...
LocalDbDirectory = N:\Common\My Toolkit Databases\
...
```

So I need to be able to interpret the shorthand notation with methods such as IO.Directory.Exists(...) or equivalent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Relying on environment variables within .NET application is not very safe, what if set USERPROFILE=~/, then System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) will ALWAYS return false, but set USERPROFILE=. or set USERPROFILE=/ somtimes may work, depending on a current worknig folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run them through [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path)`;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) where path is `@"%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\My Toolkit\"` (There is no harm in doing this for paths that do not contain `%%` formatted tokens)

Comment: That will be why there's nothing under the IO namespace then *roll eyes*... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the short-hands are valid environment variables, you can resolve their value:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string val = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%");
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

As of .NET 4, special folder support includes user profile:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```